# Repeated integrals with explicit limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I started learning about iterated integration and I am not sure how
to complete this question.

We are working in 2D and from my understanding the only thing
I have to find are the limits of integration (and the right order in which they go) from those domains.

How could I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the straight forward way is to divide the area to several parts with the up and down edge easy to express, for example, they are 
$$I_1=\int _{-2}^{-1}dx\int _{-2}^{2}fdy+\int _{-1}^{1}dx\int _{1}^{2}fdy+\int _{-1}^{1}dx\int _{-2}^{-1}fdy+\int _{1}^{2}dx\int _{-2}^{2}fdy$$
$$I_2=\int _{-1}^{0}dx\int _{-1}^{-1-x}fdy+\int _{-1}^{0}dx\int _{1+x}^{1}fdy+\int _{0}^{1}dx\int _{-1}^{-1+x}fdy+\int _{0}^{1}dx\int _{1-x}^{1}fdy$$
$$I_3=\int _{-2}^{0}dx\int _{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}fdy+\int _{0}^{2}dx\int _{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}fdy+\int _{0}^{2}dx\int _{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}fdy$$

Also, I think consider it as subtraction will be OK, for example
$$I_1=\int _{-2}^2\int _{-2}^2fdxdy-\int _{-1}^1\int _{-1}^1fdxdy$$
$$I_3=\int _{-2}^2dx\int _{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dyf-\int _{0}^2dx\int _{-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}dyf$$

When $f$ has some symmetry with x, y, it can be simplified.